# How to create a new rails app from existing source?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3, github

I saw somewhere not long ago that in 3.0.4 or 3.0.5 there is ability to do something like that:

```
rails new myapp -m https://git@github.com:user/app_template_repo.git
```

to make the new application from the existing sources in git repository, but I can't find the exact command right now. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone https://git@github.com:user/app_template_repo.git
```

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. This command just copies the existing repo to my computer, but I've read that there is new ability in Rails 3.0.4 that you can create new application based on the git source code.